# How to vertically align two columns of text in a table (tabular)

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

This should should be a simple question, but after reviewing other responses I still can't seem to get it working. I've simplified my example to the following:

```
\begin{tabular}{p{.5in} l }
  \begin{tabular}{p{.5in}  }
    very long first column that spans multiple row.s
  \end{tabular}
 & 
  \begin{tabular}{p{.5in}  }
    2nd column
  \end{tabular}
\end{tabular}
```

I simply want to get the text in both columns to be vertically aligned to the top. Unfortuantely Try as I might, currently the 2nd column is always vertically centered in the table.

Comment: Do you have a reason for nesting your `tabular` environments? If you remove the inner `tabular` environments, the cell contents are aligned at the top. To make a cell span several rows, you would usually use `\multirow` from the `multirow` package.

Answer (score 1):

Use `t` (for top) in the optional argument of `tabular`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{p{.5in} l }
  \begin{tabular}[t]{p{.5in}  }
    very long first column that spans multiple row.s
  \end{tabular}
 & 
  \begin{tabular}[t]{p{.5in}  }
    2nd column
  \end{tabular}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

why do you embed a tabular in a tabular?

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{p{.5in}p{.5in}}
\raggedright very long first column that spans multiple rows& 
\raggedright 2nd column
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```